# Jena SDB ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jena

i'm new with Jena SDB. i've included SDB-1.2.3.jar in class path and database is online and working with this connection string. but the program crashes on the very first line. please help me and also give me some useful tutorial links on SDB-Jena. i've alredy tried ones on their official site.
my code is from site "http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/javaapi.html"

```
StoreDesc storeDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash,
                                       DatabaseType.MySQL ) ;
   JDBC.loadDriverMySQL();
   String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/test?username=root&password=1&database=test";
   SDBConnection conn = new SDBConnection(jdbcURL, null, null) ;
   Store store = SDBFactory.connectStore(conn, storeDesc) ;
```

but the compiler give me following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/ARQException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at jenasdb.JenaSDB.main(JenaSDB.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.ARQException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: it gives me following exception too "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/update/GraphStore"

Answer (score 2):

The arq-jar file is not on your classpath. It should be distributed with jena, so try looking in a lib-directory.